# Blazor - Get object set by parent

Tags: c#, .net, blazor

I've the following piece of code:

```
@page "somePage"

<TeamsApplication RequireAuthentication="true">
    <ApplicationTemplate Context="context">
        Some HTML...
        @*context works here*@
    </ApplicationTemplate>
</TeamsApplication>

@code{
  //context doesnt work here
}
```

Inside ApplicationTemplate tag I can access context object instance, but can't do it in code section. Is there a way I could access that instance and its values?

Comment: I did reply to this but re-reading I wasn't sure it was right. Why can't you access the `Context` property from `ApplicationTemplate` code? It should be a `[Parameter]` which is in the code??

Comment: I'm sorry if it wasn't clear. The code shown is not from ApplicationTemplate component. Instead, is from other component wrapped inside ApplicationTemplate. The parementer is correctly set in ApplicationTemplate component.

Comment: Properties cascade _down_, not up - so setting a Context property here won't work. I'll suggest an approach in an answer

Answer (score 1):

A familiar problem, building a page from a set of components that want to share data and state.  You can wire them all up together, but you soon end up with spaghetti.

The solution is to separate your data and state from the UI.  The UI code stays in the components, the data and state live in a service - often called a ViewService.  The service is usually Scoped i.e. one per SPA session.  Each component injects the service and then accesses the shared data/state.  You use events in the service to notify components of changes they need to react to - often a re-render.

In your question the service would hold the `context`.  Then `TeamsApplication`, `ApplicationTemplate`, `SomePage` and any other component would all inject the service and access `context`.

If you want a working example, ask, I'll add one to this answer.

Answer (score 0):

Properties normally flow down, not up. So the `Context` property won't work like that. The simplest solution I could think of is an EventCallback, so that the `ApplicationTemplate` sends a message to the parent that the Context is available

`ApplicationTemplate.razor`

```cs
    [Parameter] public EventCallback<Context> ContextChanged {  get;  set; }

    /// <summary>
    /// Context was set from somewhere
    /// </summary>
    async Task ContextSet(Context newValue)
    {
        // notify anyone listening to ContextChanged
        await ContextChanged.InvokeAsync(newValue);
    }
```

Then in your page logic you listen to this event callback:

```
<TeamsApplication>
    <ApplicationTemplate ContextChanged=HandleContextChanged>
        @* todo *@
    </ApplicationTemplate>

</TeamsApplication>

@code
{
    /// <summary>
    /// Handle event from ApplicationTemplate
    /// </summary>
    /// <param name="context"></param>
    /// <returns></returns>
    async Task HandleContextChanged(Context context)
    {
        // context is now available
        
    }

}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can create a function that accepts a parameter of the same type of your context Type and so you have access within that function, but the question is: what you need that context for?

If you need to create a custom component that need to have access to that context, pass it to another child component, then create a [Parameter] of type RenderFragment and so you can deal with it as you want.

You can even create a local function that renders a RenderFragment but the Razor syntax for that kind of stuff is quite akward and a bit bugged

For example I have a method like this

```
public RenderFragment DefaultActionTemplate(PanelAction action) =>@:@{
      if (action.IsToggle) {
         <div>Toggle</div>
      }
      else {
         <div>Button</div>
      }
   }
   ;
```

You can do the same and use your context Type instead of my PanelAction, the concept is the same

As I told you tho, the syntax is awkward and the semicolon you see at the end, need to be on a new line and can't be next the closing curly braket
see this issue: https://github.com/dotnet/aspnetcore/issues/11612